# How can I use Yarn to download Sharepoint Framework (SPFx) dependencies, for offline use on a VM which is not connected to the internet?

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-framework

I am starting to read and learn about SharePoint Framework (SPFx).

My development environment is a VM on a machine that does not have access to the internet.

How would I go collect all the dependencies using **Yarn** on my laptop, and then moving them to the VM? 
(I can install Node.js and Yarn using their installers on the VM.)

Which *yarn* commands would I use to save the dependencies offline?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy /node_modules from the root folder of your SPFx project from your laptop to the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I actually end up using the yarn-offline-mirror method.

1. First installed NodeJS and Yarn on a computer with internet. Then setup the yarn-offline-mirror folder to collect all the dependencies.
2. Then added Yeoman and Gulp, and the SP Generator. All the dependency .tgz files are stored in yarn-offline-mirror.
3. I installed NodeJS and Yarn on the VM with the installers.
4. With the help of [this blog](https://assafmo.github.io/2018/04/11/yarn-offline.html) about working with Yarn offline, I copied the files *yarn.lock*, *package.json* and the *~/yarn-offline-mirror/* folder to the VM without internet and added the dependencies while adding `--offline` to the `add` commands.
5. Finally installed Yeoman SharePoint generator with `yo @microsoft/sharepoint --package-manager yarn --offline`.

and Done!

...however, as I mentioned at the start I'm just starting with SPFx, I need to continue playing around and check if another other errors come up.